# reallocate array in mex function

Tags: c++, mex

In the following code in each iteration the size of the array is increased by one
and an element in this position is assigned. While in the ReallocArray there is no bad memory allocation
when the excecution returns in the for loop a bat memory allocation appears and it crashes.

Any ideas?

```
void ReallocArray(float* OutputArray, int NewCapacity){

    if(!(OutputArray = (float*)mxRealloc(OutputArray, sizeof(float)*NewCapacity)))
        mexErrMsgTxt("Out of Memory");
    mexMakeMemoryPersistent(OutputArray);
    mexPrintf("Memory allocation successful!\n");
}


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], // output vars
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) // input vars

    float* InputMatrix = (float*) mxGetData(prhs[0]);
    float* LocalOutputData = NULL;
    int LocalOutputDataSize = 0; //initial size

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
        ReallocArray( LocalOutputData, ++LocalOutputDataSize );
        LocalOutputData[ LocalOutputDataSize - 1 ] = InputMatrix[i]; 
   }

   return;
}
```

PS: Of course there are more than 5 elements in `InputMatrix`.

Comment: Anyway I think a reference is needed. `void ReallocArray(float*& OutputArray, int NewCapacity)`

Comment: I'm assuming this is academic, because there is no reason to grow the array like this for a simple copy.

Comment: Thanks **chappjc** I think I found it. And yes it is academic.

Comment: The referenced fixed it, huh? Ooops.   ;)

Comment: Yes, I just verify it right now. Sorry, for the disturbance.

Comment: Based on the last edits, I'm guessing you just discovered `mxSetData` and `mxSetDimensions`?  ;)